# printing a dic>dic value

Tags: python

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}
```

I can only print the first dic (coffee names) keys, but for some reason I cannot reach the costs...

```
for item in MENU:
    for item2,cost in item:
        print(f" {item} {cost} ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't magically fetch a dictionary value without passing the key name (`'cost'` in your case). Try this as an example:

```
for item, data in MENU.items():
    print(f"Item {item}, cost: {data['cost']}")
```

this should print

```
Item espresso, cost: 1.5
Item latte, cost: 2.5
Item cappuccino, cost: 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you! But, why couldn't it just be MENU instead of MENU.items()?

Comment: Iterating over a dictionary will only return its keys (drink names in your case). If you want to access both key and the corresponding value you should iterate over [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)